# How to filter between dates in typeorm without using raw query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, date, typeorm

```
findByPlayerIdOnWeek(player_id: string, date: Date): Promise<CheckIn> {
  date = new Date(); // get current date
  const first = date.getDate() - date.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
  const last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6

  const startOfTheWeek = new Date(date.setDate(first)).toUTCString();
  const endOfTheWeek = new Date(date.setDate(last)).toUTCString();

  return this.ormRepository.findOne({
    where: {
      player_id,
      check_in_date {
        startOfTheWeek
        endOfTheWeek
      },
    },
  })
```

}

**Question**

I need to filter two dates in a week, that is, the beginning and end of the week to know if the athlete performed 3 check-ins during that time interval. Dates always are hard for me so its a little confusing.

I'm using Typeorm with PostgreSQL database, where I save the date on which the athlete checks in. If he performs 3 check-ins during the week, then he will no longer be able to check in during that week.

Does anyone know how I can check if the dates on which the athlete logged in are during the current week's time range?

Thank you very much

I tried to objectively describe the question I'm having.

I hope to get a resolution to my question

I still haven't got any solution